# Python - Pass URL string to extract components

Tags: python, parsing

I have an example of URL string:

https://subdomain.domain.com/#/1.170708054/22969551/0

I need to extract:

1.170708054 and 22969551 values

Previously I was using URLPARSE however the structure has changed and no longer has ID=1.170708054 and ID2 = 22969551.

Comment: can you show the urlparse code?

Comment: paste your code what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example program does maybe what you want, but maybe you have to adjust it to the structure of the url's you expect.

```
import re

txt = "https://subdomain.domain.com/#/1.170708054/22969551/0"
x = re.search("#/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/", txt)
if x:
    een = x.group(1)
    twee = x.group(2)
else:
    print ('no match')
print(een) 
print (twee)
```

The two strings after the # part of the url between slashes are captured and printed.